# AppleScript to click on webpage with colour

Tags: javascript, applescript

I am using AppleScript to open online meeting. [Here among 5 tabs i should click on the green colour(current meeting) tab.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBr1C.jpg) Any idea how to getElementBy 'background' colour.

```
to clickClassName(theClassName, elementnum)
    
    tell application "Safari"
        
        do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('" & theClassName & "')[" & elementnum & "].click();" in document 1
        
    end tell
    
end clickClassName

tell application "Safari"
    activate
    open location "https://myclass.lpu.in/"
    delay 5
    
    tell application "System Events" to tell process "Safari"
        keystroke "USERNAME"
        delay 0.2
        keystroke tab
        delay 0.2
        keystroke "PASSWORD"
        delay 1
        keystroke return
        delay 5
    end tell
end tell

clickClassName("btn stretched-link text-white w-100", 0)
```

Here at last i need to add a function to open that green tab.

[As in the picture there are 5  tags for 5 meetings ClassName is same so only background colour is  unique in them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBr1C.jpg)

Comment: The background attribute isn't an attribute at all, it's just within the styles attribute.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I will help you with the solution. You must not credit my solution to another user, otherwise I will never help you again. Add following to the end of your script.

```
set classNames to {"fc-time-grid-event fc-event fc-start fc-end", "fc-time-grid-event fc-event fc-start fc-end fc-time-grid-event-inset"}
set notFounded to true

tell application "Safari"
    repeat with className in classNames
        if notFounded then
            
            -- count all elements of  indicated class
            set theCount to (do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName(className).length;" in document 1) as integer
            
            if theCount > 0 then -- find element with "background: green" and click it
                repeat with i from 0 to theCount - 1
                    set theStyle to (do JavaScript "(document.getElementsByClassName(className)[" & i & "]).getAttribute('style');" in document 1) as text
                    if theStyle contains "background: green;" then
                        do JavaScript "(document.getElementsByClassName(className)[" & i & "]).click();" in document 1
                        set notFounded to false
                        exit repeat
                    end if
                end repeat
            end if
            
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: can u pls modify the code accordingly since there are 2 classNames..... the ClassName will be  **'fc-time-grid-event fc-event fc-start fc-end'**  or it will be  **'fc-time-grid-event fc-event fc-start fc-end fc-time-grid-event-inset'**   but there will be only one element with background green.